# Generar un vector con longitud establecida por el usuario con números aleatorios

Tags: c, array

necesito generar un vector con un arreglo con longitud establecida por el usuario y que sea de numeros aleatorios, pero parece ser que me equivoque en algo porque los numeros aleatorios que genera son los mismos en todo el vector ¿Alguien sabe en que me equivoque? necesito ayuda urgente

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <conio.h>

#define L 100
int A[L];
void asignacion(int &);
void imprime(int &);

int main(){
int n;
printf("Introduce la longitud del arreglo");
scanf("%d",&n);
asignacion(n);
imprime(n);
getch();
}

void asignacion(int &x){
int dato,i;
for(i=0;i<x;i++)
   {        
    srand(time(NULL));
    dato=rand();
    A[i]=dato;

    }
}

void imprime(int &x){
int i;
   for(i=0;i<x;i++)
    {
    printf(" %d",A[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La inicialización para poder usar `rand` debe hacerse sólo una vez, vos lo estás haciendo por cada ejecución dentro del `for`. La línea:

```
srand(time(NULL));
```

debe ir fuera del `for` (antes, naturalmente).

Comment: Es cierto, muchas amigo ya quedo solucionado